# AttributeError: 'SeleniumClient' object has no attribute 'chrome_options'

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I'm trying to run a code to do some web scraping in Twitter but I keep having an error that I don't manage to solve. I guess it is related to selenium webdriver, but I am not very familiar with it and I haven't found any solutions so far.

This is the code:

```
import pandas
import numpy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
class SeleniumClient(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #Initialization method. 
        self.chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions('D:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver', options=self.chrome_options)
        self.chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        self.chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        self.chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')

        # you need to provide the path of chromdriver in your system
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\Google\chromedriver.exe')

        self.base_url = 'https://twitter.com/search?q='

    def get_tweets(self, query):
        ''' 
        Function to fetch tweets. 
        '''
        try: 
            self.browser.get(self.base_url+query)
            time.sleep(2)

            body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')

            for _ in range(3000):
                body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
                time.sleep(0.3)

            timeline = self.browser.find_element_by_id('timeline')
            tweet_nodes = timeline.find_elements_by_css_selector('.tweet-text')

            return pd.DataFrame({'tweets': [tweet_node.text for tweet_node in tweet_nodes]})

        except: 
            print("Selenium - An error occured while fetching tweets.")

#this next line is the one that gives the error, but it must be located in the class

selenium_client = SeleniumClient()
tweets_df = selenium_client.get_tweets('AI and Deep learning')
```

This is what the error says:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-3bd40446c1fd> in <module>
----> 1 selenium_client = SeleniumClient()
      2 #tweets_df = selenium_client.get_tweets('AI and Deep learning')

<ipython-input-3-f0c81bf234aa> in __init__(self)
      4     def __init__(self):
      5         #Initialization method.
----> 6         self.chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions('D:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver', options=self.chrome_options)
      7         self.chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
      8         self.chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

AttributeError: 'SeleniumClient' object has no attribute 'chrome_options'
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are using [selenium3](/questions/tagged/selenium3) and using `Chrome()` the default argument is **`executable_path`** which takes the absolute path of the ***ChromeDriver*** executable. Where as you have passed the absolute path of the ***Chrome*** executable.

Moreover, `ChromeOptions()` object doesn't needs any location as an argument.

Effectively your code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

class SeleniumClient(object):
    def __init__(self):
    #Initialization method. 
    self.chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    self.chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    self.chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    self.chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')

    # you need to provide the path of chromdriver in your system
    self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\Google\chromedriver.exe', options=self.chrome_options)
    self.base_url = 'https://twitter.com/search?q='
```